# Highlight selected item in navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="group" id="example-one">
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Theatres</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>                                   
  </div>
</div>
```

given above is my navabar. what should i do to make the selected item in the navbar highlighted? should i use any `jquery` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$('#example-one a').click(function(e) {
    $('#example-one a').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $(this).addClass('current_page_item');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/YSYpw/54/)

Comment: i tried your code, but addclass ('current_page_item') isn't working with me

Comment: Did you check the console? May be there will be some error in the page. This code is working fine in "DEMO"

Comment: Did you add the style for the class?

Comment: ok its kind of working but first item in navbar always have bgcolor(it has class="current-page_item")

Comment: Ok. You want to have class="current-page_item" when loading for the first time? If you dont want it you can remove it. I did that in my "DEMO". So do you want that on first time load?

Comment: change this `$('#example-one a')` to `$('#example-one li')`

Answer (score 2):

Here, `jquery` isn't necessary.. you can just add this `css`:

```
a:hover{
    background-color:#aaa;
    color:white;
}
a:active{
    background-color:#000;
    color:white;
}
```

with whatever color you want.

**Run this** [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5yv7y6bk/)

Just remember - `hover` must come before `active` for this to be effective.
[A reference here.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: not the way i intended. its changing color when i click, but then back to original color. i want the color to stay there as long as u are in 'Contact Us' eg( <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>).

Comment: okay then add `a:link` and `a:visited` before the existing css, and set the `a:visited` color same as `a:active` color.. that should work like you want

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which situation you want it to highlight in, there are various ways to do it, this is the one i believe will help you:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="group" id="example-one">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>//current page
      <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Theatres</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>                                   
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.group a {
    background-color: #000;
}
.group a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.active a {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Then just change the class attribute on the list element for the active page.

Comment: the order of the appearing styles is important - `hover` must come before `active` for this to be effective.. [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried your code its changing color when i select a item, but after that it changes to original color and not staying the color which i intended. i want the color in active to stay till i select a new item

Comment: @AjithN Are you trying it with the `href="#"` or an actual other page?

Comment: i tried like this :   #example-one a:active { 
 color:red;
}  so when i click a item in nav bar it changes to red but it doesn't stay red.

Comment: @AjithN I meant in the HTML element for the link, try setting up another page and linking to it, this may fix your problem, or try adding `.group a:visited { background-color: #fff; } to your CSS.

Comment: ok i didnt get u last time. and yes i am trying with actual links like this              <li><a id="classic" href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ '/site/gallery' ] ); ?>" >Gallery</a></li>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83605/discussion-between-ajith-n-and-billy-steer).

Comment: @AjithN Alright ill see if i can think up any other ways to do it, will add to OP if i can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83610/discussion-between-ajith-n-and-billy-steer).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is,

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="nav-wrap">
        <ul class="group" id="example-one">
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Theatres</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>                                   
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.group .active { background-color: #000; }
```

Depends on your requirement, add `active` class to `li` or `a` on activated item (current page).